# Flash, javascript e html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas, flash

Oi fiz um slider no flash player com o html5 canvas e publiquei agora preciso coloca-lo dentro do div do meu arquivo mas não estou conseguindo, a tela fica preta quando substituo o arquivo html feito pelo flash, e coloco na minha pagina. Estou testando em servidor local, talvez seja por isso?
Fiz um teste e coloquei dentro de um iframe e funcionou mais para um e-commerce acho que não seria bom ficar usando iframes para os sliders das paginas.

Esse e o codigo html e javascript que o flash cc criou que quero colocar dentro do meu div

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>slider</title>

     <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="slider.js"></script>

     <script>
     var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

        function init() {
           canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
         images = images||{};
         ss = ss||{};

         var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
         loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
         loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
         loader.loadFile({src:"images/slider_atlas_.json",         type:"spritesheet", id:"slider_atlas_"}, true);
         loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
     }

     function handleFileLoad(evt) {
         if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
     }

     function handleComplete(evt) {
         var queue = evt.target;
         ss["slider_atlas_"] = queue.getResult("slider_atlas_");
         exportRoot = new lib.slider();

         stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
         stage.addChild(exportRoot);
         stage.update();
         stage.enableMouseOver();

         createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
         createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
     }
     </script>
     </head>

     <body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
         <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="720" style="background-color:#000000"></canvas>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Se alguem souber qualquer coisa que pode ajudar fico agradecido!
Obrigado.

Comment: Poste o código da pagina e o código do slider, para tentarmos reproduzir seu problema.